# C# class constraints with Generic Type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, constraints

I have this generic class with a condition on the generic type:

```
public abstract class ReportModel<ReportHandler> where ReportHandler : IReportHandler
```

Then I have this Controller class

```
public abstract class ReportController<ReportModelType> : Controller
```

What I need is a condition that *ReportModelType* must inherit the abstract *ReportModel* class. The trouble is that Im then forced to give a type argument for *ReportModel*, I dont want to specify an argument. I need some kind of wildcard like this:

```
public abstract class ReportController<ReportModelType> : Controller where ReportModelType : ReportModel<*any type which satifies ReportModels contraint>
```

Can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: What do you mean, you are forced to give a type argument? I don't quite understand that part

Comment: as soon as I write *where  ReportModelType : ReportModel* I will get a error saying that I must provide a type argument for ReportModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
public interface IReportHandler
{

}

public abstract class ReportModel<ReportHandler>
    where ReportHandler : IReportHandler
{
}

public abstract class ReportController<ReportModelType, ReportHandler>
    where ReportModelType : ReportModel<ReportHandler>
    where ReportHandler : IReportHandler
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a wildcard for a generic type in C#

There are two solutions you might consider however

**Make it an interface**

```
public interface IReportModel
{}

public abstract class ReportModel<ReportHandler> : IReportModel 
    where ReportHandler : IReportHandler
```

use that interface:

```
... ReportController<ReportModelType> : Controller 
    where ReportModelType : IReportModel
```

**Consider making the ReportModel ReportHandler type part of your next class**

```
... ReportController<ReportModelType> : Controller 
     where ReportModelType : ReportModel<ReportHandler> 
     where ReportHandler : IReportHandler
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a generic wildcard in C#, so all you can do is to find an alternative.

I suggest that you add another generic type parameter `ReportHandler` to `ReportController`, constraint the new type parameter to implement `IReportHandler` and make `ReportModelType` implement `ReportModel<ReportHandler>`.

```
public abstract class ReportController<ReportModelType, ReportHandler> : Controller
    where ReportHandler : IReportHandler
    where ReportModelType: ReportModel<ReportHandler>
```